# Replace part of string in a column with words in another column based on condition - python

Tags: python, string, replace, multiple-columns

I have a dataset with 3 columns.

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mWpU.png)

I need to lookup the entire word in "word" column in the "sentence" column and replace it with the entire word in the "replacement" column. No need to create a separate column for the replaced sentence.

I am expecting an output like this -

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFUUi.png)

Can anyone please help me with this in Python? I have tried some things with the replace() function but it doesn't seem to be working. This is what I tried -

```
new_col = []
for s in df["sentence"]:
    for index, w in enumerate(df["word"]):
        if w in s:
            a = ". ".join([s.replace(w, syno) for syno in df["replacement"][index]])
    new_col.append(a)

df["new_col"] = new_col
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please add the code you have tried with, then we can help you troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: Hi @user56700  I tried with a new column, but I won't need that
new_col = []
for s in df["sentence"]:
    for index, w in enumerate(df["word"]):
        if w in s:
            a = ". ".join([s.replace(w, syno) for syno in df["replacement"][index]])
    new_col.append(a)

df["new_col"] = new_col

Comment: Don't put it in the comments, edit your question and add it there, remember to format it as code.

Comment: Got it. Done editing! @user56700

Answer (score 0):

here is a working example :

```
sentence = "Google is a website"
before = "Google"
after = "Brave"

sentence = sentence.replace(before, after)
print(sentence)
```

> Brave is a website

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Medaillek. But could you suggest what I can do when the lookup words, replacement words, and the sentences are in separate columns?